# how to merge two object array for angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I am trying to merge two or more object arrays with angular js.**

```
var app = angular.module('bookingApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});

app.controller('bookingCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.init = function(){
       $http({
              method: 'get',
              url: 'http://mmres.baganthandehotel.net/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
              data: $.param({'search' : ''}),
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
            })
        .success(function(data){
            var list1 = data;
            angular.isObject(list1);
            //console.log(list1);

        });
        $http({
              method: 'get',
              url: 'http://mmres.classique-inn.com/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
              data: $.param({'search' : ''}),
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
            })
        .success(function(data){
            var list2 = data;
            //console.log(list2);

        });
        $scope.myConcatenatedData = list1.concat(list2);
        console.log(myConcatenatedData);
    }; 
});
```

I get two object arrays as list1 and list2 from two controllers.Now I want to merge list1 and list2 as an array. Please help me for this solution.

Comment: what does the `console.log` show ? I guess it's giving undefined, so you should probably nest your second http request in the success of the first one and concat in the success of the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for both HTTP requests to complete, then combine the lists. `$http` returns a promise, so you can use `Promise.all` (perhaps `$q.all` as this is Angular) to wait for them both to be done. See comments:

```
app.controller('bookingCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.init = function(){
        var list1, list2;                    // Declare them here
        Promise.all([                        // Wait for both requests to complete (perhaps this should be $q.all)
           $http({
                  method: 'get',
                  url: 'http://mmres.baganthandehotel.net/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
                  data: $.param({'search' : ''}),
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
                })
            .success(function(data){
                list1 = data;
            }),
            $http({
                  method: 'get',
                  url: 'http://mmres.classique-inn.com/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
                  data: $.param({'search' : ''}),
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
                })
            .success(function(data){
                list2 = data;
            })
        ]).then(function() {                 // Then concat the lists
            $scope.myConcatenatedData = list1.concat(list2);
        });
    }; 
});
```

Comment: Hello Mr T.J. Crowder,It is ok to merge two arrays.But I want to merge two or more arrays.How can I try to merge more than 2 arrays?

Comment: @MrMyo: If you're asking specifically about the merging part, what I'd probably do is have a result array (`result = []`) and then a series of `push` calls: `result.push.apply(result, arr1); result.push.apply(result, arr2); result.push.apply(result, arr3);` (probably in a loop). (In ES2015 that would be much prettier: `result.push(...arr1); result.push(...arr2);`) If you're asking about a series of `$http` requests, build up an array of their return values (their promises) and then give that array to `$q.all` (or `Promise.all`). It will wait for all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Invoke second `$http` request in the success handler of the first `$http`.

As `ajax` is asynchronous in nature, by the time you are applying `.concat`, both the variables are `undefined`

```js
var app = angular.module('bookingApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
  return function(input, start) {
    if (input) {
      start = +start; //parse to int
      return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
  }
});

app.controller('bookingCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://mmres.baganthandehotel.net/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
        data: $.param({
          'search': ''
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      })
      .success(function(data1) {
        $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://mmres.classique-inn.com/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
            data: $.param({
              'search': ''
            }),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
          })
          .success(function(data2) {
            $scope.myConcatenatedData = data1.concat(data2);
            console.log(myConcatenatedData);
          });
      });
  };
});
```

*Edit:* As suggested by great [**T.J. Crowder**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder), there is no need to delay the invokation of second `$http` request hence [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) could be used or `Promise` as explained in his answer.

```js
var app = angular.module('bookingApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
  return function(input, start) {
    if (input) {
      start = +start; //parse to int
      return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
  }
});

app.controller('bookingCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $q.all([$http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://mmres.baganthandehotel.net/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
        data: $.param({
          'search': ''
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }),
      $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://mmres.classique-inn.com/mmresadmin/invoicejson.php',
        data: $.param({
          'search': ''
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      })
    ]).then(function(response) {
      $scope.myConcatenatedData = response[0].concat(response[1]);
      console.log(myConcatenatedData);
    })
  };
});
```

Comment: That certainly works, but there's no particular reason to delay the second request if it doesn't need to use information from the first as part of the request; they could easily be in parallel.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I was about to edit with `$q.all` but as usual, you got first :)

Comment: *"by great T.J. Crowder"* LOL Now I'm going to get a fat head. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, You certainly are :)